# I cannot see postgres.auto.conf in Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, alter

I used ALTER SYSTEM to change parameters in my Postgres instances in Ubuntu and Windows.

In windows, I can see postgres.auto.conf populated.

Yet in Ubuntu, I cannot see postgres.auto.conf. Is there something I am missing?
How to confirm my changes took effect in Postgres on Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot be certain how you set up PostgreSQL and how you created the data directory, but let's assume you used the PGDG binary packages and used `pg_createcluster`.

The problem is probably that with such a setup, the configuration files are stored in a directory (under `/etc`) different from the data directory (which is under `/var/lib`). Now `postgresql.auto.conf` is stored in the data directory, *not* under `/etc` with the configuration files that you are supposed to edit by hand.